# Installing Python Module - SpiDev

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2010, module

I am working on a project that involves programming the raspberry pi windows 10 IoT core. I'm programming it in python, however I need to install the python module SpiDev. I have tried various ways all that return the same error as shown below. I have installed Visual C++ 2010 (Correct version for Python 3.4) as the compiler and I work in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. From a command prompt I have tried installing with the following:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\jedho\\Downloads\\py-spidev-master\\py-spidev-master\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\jedho\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
```

with

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:\Users\jedho\Downloads\py-spidev-master\py-spidev-master\setup.py install
```

Which contains the directory I downloaded SpiDev from

and via PIP with

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.exe install spidev
```

But all return the same error

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -I/usr/src/linux/include -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tcinstall_spidev_module_EDIT.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\install_spidev_module_EDIT.obj install_spidev_module_EDIT.c c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'install_spidev_module_EDIT.c': No such file or directory error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: Same problem happening in Python 2.7 for Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens since some software is platform-oriented. It seems like Windows does not support native RaspberryPI SpiDev.

[How to emulate/mock functionality](https://github.com/TCAllen07/raspi-device-mocks) on different platform. Good explanation with wrapping example.

[SpiDev](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev) which not likely work with Windows.

As temporary solution, the code can be written as small chunks in iPython on dedicated device and transferred to your Windows-based IDE.